# MVC print the connection string in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, connection-string

i need to print a connection string from Web.config in _Layout.cshtml, any idea how to?

Web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DConnectionString" connectionString="EnvName" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> [Print EnvName here] </a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not familiar with Razor, i saw your link i'll read about it, thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">  
    @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DConnectionString"]
</a>
```

This uses [Razor](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29) syntax to access the [System.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.